# Why am I getting an error 'Cannot read proprty itemId of undefined' even though my function works?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex

I'm building a want list app using Google Cloud Firestore to store user data. I have several functions that allow users to update item on their want lists, for example how soon they want the item. From what I can see, the functions work because the data updates in Firestore and on the DOM. However, I get an error message from Firestore that says: "Cannot read property 'itemId' of undefined". Could anyone tell me why this is happening?

Here is some code from the app:

From the store:

```
    changePriority({ commit }, payload) {
      commit("SET_LOADING", true);

      firebase
        .collection("wishList")
        .doc(payload.itemId)
        .update({
          priority: payload.newSelectedPriority,
        })
        .then(() => {
          commit("SET_LOADING", false);
          commit("UPDATE_PRIORITY");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          commit("SET_ERROR", err);
          commit("SET_LOADING", true);
        });
    },
```

From the DOM elements:

```
    updatePriority() {
      this.$store.dispatch("changePriority", {
        itemId: this.itemId,
        newSelectedPriority: this.newSelectedPriority,
      });
    },
```

```
  props: {
    priority: {
      type: String,
    },

    itemId: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
```

```
       <v-card-actions>
          <v-btn @click="closeDialog" color="red" text>
            <v-icon left>mdi-cancel</v-icon>
            Cancel</v-btn
          >
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-btn
            @click.prevent="updatePriority"
            :loading="loading"
            :disabled="loading"
            color="blue"
            text
            :itemId="itemId"
            ><v-icon left>mdi-check</v-icon> Update</v-btn
          >
        </v-card-actions>
```

If you need any more code or anything more specific, please let me know.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Which one is undefined, `payload.itemId` or `this.itemId`? Also, why do you have `:itemId="itemId"` on your button?

Comment: This error is happening because the `payload` value received in `changePriority` is `undefined`. Please log the value before dispatching it and inside the function in order to further track the error.